# JS Component will not display on page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

My component will not display on the page.  There are no errors or any other warnings/messages.  I console log the value of gameData and all the data is as it should be.  Here's the exported function:

```
export default function AllGameDeals( gameData ){

    const dealArr = new Array()

    const deals = () => {
        gameData.deals.map((deal) => {
            const imageSrc = `https://www.cheapshark.com/img/stores/icons/${(parseInt(deal.storeID)-1)}.png`
            deal.imageSrc = imageSrc
            dealArr.push(deal)
        })
        return dealArr
    }
    deals()

    return (
        <div>
        {dealArr.forEach(gameDeal => (  
          <Box
                key={gameDeal.dealID}
                display={{ md: "flex" }}
                boxShadow="dark-lg"
                p={4}
                >
                <Box flexShrink={0}>
                    <Image borderRadius="lg"
                        width={{ md: 40 }}
                        height={{ md: 20 }}
                        src={gameData.info.thumb}
                        alt={gameData.info.title} />
                </Box>
                <Box>
                    <Image
                        src={gameDeal.imageSrc}
                        alt={gameDeal.storeID} />
                </Box>
                <Box>
                    <Text>{gameDeal.price}</Text>
                    
                </Box>
                </Box>
        ))}
        </div>
        
    )
    
}
```

I feel like I am missing something very obvious...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing from dealArr.forEach to dealArr.map.

The reason is that .forEach returns nothing, but .map returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `.map` instead of `.forEach` because `.forEach` doesn't actually return a value

Other possible improvements:

1. Use `useEffect` to fetch data on mount of the component (instead of fetching everytime)
2. Use `useState` to "persist" your state within the component